# PHP: Store multiple select values in array

Tags: php, arrays

There are maximum 8 `<select name="a">` and I need to store these values in an array

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];

if (isset($a, $b)) {
    foreach ($products as $thisProduct) {
        if ($thisProduct->getId() == $a) {
        //do something & store in array
            switch($b){
                case "one":
                //do something
                break;

                case "two":
                //do something
                break;

                case "three":
                //do something
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//call array and make array_sum()...
```

How do I store these in an array so I could use this array for making calculations?

**UPDATE**

There are also 8 `input` fields with an amount. This `input` multiply with the value of `$a`.

```
foreach ($products as $thisProduct) {

    foreach ($a as $value) {
        if ($thisProduct->getId() == $value) {
            $multiply = ($thisProduct->getMultiply($amount));
            array_push($array, $multiply);  
        }
    }
}
```

How can I link each `input` to the `select name="[a]"`?

Comment: use `<select name="a[]">`. it will convert post variable into array

Comment: Of topic: Instead of multiple `if` statements, can't you use `switch` statement ? A

Comment: @krishna and how do I store other variables in the array?

Comment: @TismonVarghese That would be better, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `<select name=a[]>` and use this code

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
foreach($a as $value){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: and how do you use it with another for each?

Comment: $a is an array your `<select>` variables